Posh-Git PowerShell Module for Standard User in Windows 11
I can install posh-git just fine when running PowerShell 7 as an Administrator and Import-Module posh-git works fine and my git branch is highlighted just fine.
However if I open the PowerShell 7 or Terminal on Windows 11 (as Standard User), then posh-git doesn't work. Running Install-Module posh-git returns to prompt with no errors and Get-Module returns nothing. ExecutionPolicy is set to Unrestricted:

Running Terminal as Administrator works just fine:

On Windows 10 I had none of these issues. I could run posh-git and oh-my-posh as a Standard User just fine.

Verify the path to the script in question is contained within the system variable you are attempting to use as a nonprivileged user.

No, they are both Powershell 7. In the first I just did a cls. I don't get what path to the script I should verify? There is no script when I just run a simple command to install a module like Install-Module posh-git.
